reactive variable not registering correctly in header
I'm new to Vue 3 and encountering an odd behavior. I'm checking the authentication state in my app.js where I mount the Vue app:
import { store } from './components/store/store';

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // perform some authentication check and set store.isLoggedIn state
  axios
    .post('/api/is-loggined', {
      auth_token: localStorage.auth_token,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const isLoggined = response.data;
      store.isLoggedIn = Boolean(isLoggined);
})

In my header component, I want to call a certain API based on whether the user is logged in or not. Here, if I use the watch method, everything functions correctly. However, when I switch to the created or mounted methods, they don't seem to work. The store.isLoggedIn variable is true when using watch, but false in any other case. Yet, both created and mounted methods work in other components. Why could this be?
I use the vue's built in state management.
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export const store = reactive({
  isLoggedIn: false,
});

code that works in watch but not in other methods:
watch: {
      'store.isLoggedIn'(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          axios
            .post('/api/get-user-data', {
              auth_token: localStorage.auth_token,
            })
            .then((response) => {
              this.userData = response.data;
            });
        }
      },
    },


Please share how do you set the isLoggedIn value

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It's safe to assume there's race condition. It's unknown how Header and "other components" are related to the app. If Header  is outside router view, which is kind of expected, its rendering is not blocked by beforeEach

@BoussadjraBrahim updated the post to include the setting method

@yadsnasx please provide sample of what works in Header as watch but does not work otherwise

@Dimava added to the post!
